# What is the reason an app can start running normally and switch to an expo dev version after closing and re-launched it?

Tags: react-native, expo

I develop a RN app using expo. I have deployed via expo a series of versions on iOS and Android, all went fine until this strange behaviour.
I have version X on app store and a developing a new version on expo. Strangely, the officiel app displays one version I have published with "expo publish" but not deployed on the stores.
I have cleaned my phone, removing expo and the app. I have downloaded anew the app version X from the store and this is what happens: the app opens and run normally. If I close the app (removing it from the list of background processes) and reopen it, it display the version under dev I have just "expo publish"-ed.
Is it a know strange issue ? What could have went wrong with my process ?
Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: You have published a dev version to the update channel that is used by your production version. If you have not created different channels, then all your builds are published to the default channel. Set build profiles in eas.json, specify releaseChannel.

Comment: Hello @Dmitro_, Thanks a lot for your comment. Really helpful as I did not pay attention to release channel while building the application. for production with "eas build' and for test with "expo publish". So if I understand well, a production version which is on the Apple or Google store relies on a channel managed by Expo ? And if so, I can change a production version bypassing the review process of Apple and Google ?

Comment: Yes, you can send OTA updates without a review. But users who download the app for the first time will not see the latest changes, they will need to restart the app to see them. Therefore, you need to work with them manually - [docs link)](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/updates/)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitro_. So potentially an update bypassing the review process can contain artefacts that break the Apple or Google rules, right ? Or Apple and Google still have control upon such OTA updates and can react upon any new features that would break their rules ?

Comment: I don't think they can check it. Updates are downloaded from the expo server by the app itself. It is better to check for updates well, if you violate the rules, there is a risk that you will no longer be able to upload applications to stores.